# Store a JSON object in a JSON array golang

Tags: json, go

I have this JSON Object :

```
  {
    "name": "test.counter",
    "value": 1.234,
    "ts": 1234567890  
  }
```

And I would like to store the entire thing in a JSON array so it could look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test.counter",
    "value": 1.234,
    "ts": 1234567890
  }
]
```

How can I do this? I'm kind of new to Golang.
**EDIT:**
I'm creating the JSON object

```
output := &Output{
    Name:  url[0],
    Milli: ms,
    Epoch: time.Now().Unix(),
    }
out1, _ := json.Marshal(output)
```

Comment: How is your JSON object coming through on the backend? Is it coming through a request body?

Comment: Check the edit for the updated code

Comment: Just add the "[" and "]" to the string you get after marshaling. No need for cleverness here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just crate a slice of Output structs, and you can just Marshal that.

```
output := Output{
    Name:  url[0],
    Milli: ms,
    Epoch: time.Now().Unix(),
    }

outputs := []Output{output}
out1, _ := json.Marshal(outputs)
```